# undefined error for the text box using usereducer hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Am learning use reducer hooks. Below code, I have facing an issue with an undefined error while executing. There is two text box. If I type the text it has to show the results. But here, after submitting the form. Am getting the **undefined** message for both the text box. Let me know what I have made the mistakes.

```
function ReducerFour() {
const initialState = {
    users: [
      { name: 'alan', age: 30 },
      { name: 'messi', age: 30 }
    ]
  };


const ADD_USER = 'ADD_USER';

const appReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return {
        users: [
          ...state.users,
          { 
            payload: action.payload
          }
        ]
      };
  }
};


  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    appReducer,
    initialState
  );


  const addUser = () => {
    const name = document.getElementById('form-name-input')
      .value;
    const age = document.getElementById('form-age-input')
      .value;

    const newUser = { name, age };

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_USER,
      payload: newUser
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {state.users.map(user => (
        <div>{`${user.name}   ${user.age}`}</div>
      ))}
      <div className="form">
        <div className="form-name">
          <label>name:</label>
          <input id="form-name-input" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-age">
          <label>age:</label>
          <input id="form-age-input" />
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => addUser()}>Add user</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ReducerFour
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the fix.

```
const appReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_USER:
        return {
          users: [
            ...state.users,
              action.payload
          ]
        };
        default:
          return state;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Working. Thanks!. 
Can you please clear my doubts? It would be helpful to understand the concept.
1. Initialstate name and age is assigned inside the bracket then why you removed the curly braces from the switch case ADD_USER.
2. Why you removed payload?

Comment: action.payload contains new user object. it has to be added to the state.users array.
state.users => [{ name: 'alan', age: 30 },
        { name: 'messi', age: 30 }]
action.payload => { name: 'Nilesh', age: 30 }